# Ruby 1.9 - Selecting element from 2D array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Assume I have following 2D array

```
sample  = [["Tom",1],["Jerry",2]]
```

I would like to fetch "Jerry" from the array.
Currently I am using

```
sample.select{|i| i if i[1] == 2}[0][0]
```

I also tried

```
sample.select{|i| i if i[1] == 2}.first.first # Returns "Jerry" - OK
sample.select{|i| i[0] if i[1] == 2}          # Returns ["Jerry",2] - NOT OK
```

If there is any better way to fetch element, please help.

Comment: I don't understand. If you know `sample` contains a pair `["Jerry",x]` there is no point in extracting `"Jerry"`. If you want to know if there is pair whose first element is `"Jerry"`, you could use `sample.map(&:first).include?("Jerry")`. If you want to extract a pair whose first element is `"Jerry"`, if there is one, `then sample.find { |s,_| s == "Jerry" }`. Which is it? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get all names, you can try this:

```
sample.collect(&:first)
# => ["Tom", "Jerry"]
```

However, as in your question you just want the first element's name, you can try this:

```
sample.first.first
# => "Tom"
```

If your search depend on name "Tom", then:

```
sample.detect{|i| i.first == "Tom"}.first
# => "Tom"
```

Returning name on basis of second element's value:

```
sample.detect{|i| i[1] == 1}.first
# => "Tom"
```

Comment: Thanks. However both does not solve my problem if I want Jerry.

Comment: @ramya I made edit for namewise seach. please check. I didnot do that at first as your question mentioned only to find Tom.

Comment: Thanks. I want Tom based on second element of ["Tom",1 ]
it is like return "Tom" if i == 1. Please re-read my edited question.

Comment: @ramya I have edited it accordingly. Hope it helps :)

Comment: It works. Thanks :).  I am hunting for still better approach. Please refer the last answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sample  = [["Tom",1],["Jerry",2]]
sample_hash = Hash[sample]
```

Now you can (given the condition that keys, i.e. first elements are unique, also if values are repeated then first key will be the output of matching value) -

1. use [`Hash#key(value)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-key) for Ruby 1.9 or above:

   `sample_hash.key(1) #=> "Tom"`
2. use [`Hash#index(value)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-index) for Ruby 1.8:

   `sample_hash.index(1) #=> "Tom"`

Comment: Thanku so much. It works :).  I understand time complexity is O(1) when searching in Hash.  With respect to space complexity, is it okay to convert 2D array to Hash and then select??

Comment: This is going to fail if there is a third element in sample: `["Tom",3]` and that you want to find this "Tom" with "3".  You might lose some data due to duplicate keys when calling `Hash[sample]`.  If your input data has unique keys, then this is a perfect solution!

Comment: If you look at the source code of how `key(value` is implemented which loops and run each element(key-value pair) of the hash. It's same as doing `find`/`detect`(but rather faster since method is written in C) on an array and then taking first element of the result.

Comment: @vee : You're right. Added that in the note. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) on flattened input `sample`:

```
> sample  = [["Tom",1],["Jerry",2]]
> sample.flatten.find { |name| name == 'Tom' }
=> "Tom"
```

Updated as per OP's comment:

```
> sample.find { |name, id| id == 1 }.first
=> "Tom"
```

Comment: Thanks. I request to read my question once again.
It is 2D array and in ["Tom", 1 ] I want to retrieve Tom based on 1.
The solution you have given is for 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work for you

```
sample.flatten.first
```

or

```
sample.flatten[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a hash, but if you wanna keep it as a list then look at the function `rassoc`

```
sample  = [["Tom",1],["Jerry",2]]

p sample.rassoc(2) #=> ["Jerry",2]
p sample.rassoc(2).first #=> "Jerry"

jerry_item,_ = sample.rassoc(2)
p jerry_item => "Jerry"
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there is any better way to fetch element, please help.

```
sample.select { |i| i if i[1] == 2 }
#=> [["Jerry", 2]]
```

can be written as:

```
sample.select { |i| i[1] == 2 }
#=> [["Jerry", 2]]
```

Note that [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) returns an array. To find the first element, use [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
sample.find { |i| i[1] == 2 }
#=> ["Jerry", 2]
```

You still have to call `[0]` or `.first` to get `"Jerry"`. It might be cleaner to use a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) (or a custom class) for structured data:

```
sample = [{name: 'Tom', id: 1}, {name: 'Jerry', id: 2}]
sample.find { |h| h[:id] == 2 }[:name]
#=> "Jerry"
```

Using another hash to store these objects by their `id` attribute is another option:

```
sample_by_id = sample.map { |h| [h[:id], h] }.to_h
#=> {1=>{:name=>"Tom", :id=>1}, 2=>{:name=>"Jerry", :id=>2}}
sample_by_id[1][:name]
#=> "Jerry"
```